# Box shadow around rounded corners?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap library to quickly throw together a prototype.

Here's what my layout looks like in HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-messages container">
    <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Awesomeness!</strong> You're pretty cool.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-error fade in">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Awesomeness!</strong> You're pretty cool.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what my LESS looks like:

```
div.navbar div.navbar-messages {
    .drop-shadow(1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    div.alert {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;

        margin-bottom: 0px;

        &:last-child {
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        }
    }
}

.drop-shadow(@params) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @params;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @params;
    box-shadow: @params;
}
```

What's really weird is that the drop shadow isn't curving around the child element's curved corners:

[image]

How can I make it properly curve around the corners?

Comment: Perhaps there is a gradient background behind the button that's not being clipped by the border-radius? I can't reproduce the problem using the code you gave in the question, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53kDh/1/). (Tested in FF and IE9, you don't mention a specific browser in your question.)

Comment: @Jeroen: Your fiddle doesn't match the code here. In this question, the box shadow is on a parent element. In your fiddle, the box shadow applies to only the `div.alert` elements.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your `div.navbar div.navbar-messages` element lacks rounded corners, so the shadow appears square. As described by its name, `box-shadow` draws a shadow around the element's *box*, and not the element's *contents*, so if the box itself doesn't have rounded corners, then neither will its shadow.

You can try applying the same `border-radius` styles to `div.navbar div.navbar-messages` as well, so its shadow will curve around the corners:

```
div.navbar div.navbar-messages {
    .drop-shadow(1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    .rounded-bottom-corners(4px);

    div.alert {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;

        margin-bottom: 0px;

        &:last-child {
            .rounded-bottom-corners(4px);
        }
    }
}

.drop-shadow(@params) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @params;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @params;
    box-shadow: @params;
}

.rounded-bottom-corners(@params) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: @params;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: @params;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: @params;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: @params;
    border-bottom-right-radius: @params;
    border-bottom-left-radius: @params;
}
```

Comment: I noticed you're passing params into your css example. I did a quick search and didn't find anything helpful. Is this for proof of concept or is that actually something you can do?

Comment: @Jackson: It's a LESS feature. I just noticed now that the question isn't tagged [less], so I've added that in. You can read about it here: http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins

Answer (score 4):

I have this:

```
blockquote {
    border: none;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #666666; 
    background: rgba(255,255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 1px #888888;
    padding-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

So:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
```

That worked for me pretty well! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

yep...just put a border-radius on the div that has the shadow. Make sure border-radius value matches that of the object inside the div and they will match up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `filter:drop-shadow()` on your code instead of the default `box-shadow`

Here's an example:

```
div.navbar {
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px #44444d81);
}
```

This does the trick